# Unable to install gcc compiler

Tags: linux, gcc

I am trying to install gcc compiler using the command:

```
yum install gcc
```

but I am getting the error as:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I solve this? My [original question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072356/unable-to-install-perl-modules-on-linux).

Comment: Which flavor & version of Linux are you running?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago) @heavyd

Comment: You may be experiencing a similar problem to this user: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25562/installing-gcc-on-rhel-6-1

Comment: @MC10 thanks for your help. my vm is not registered in rhn.hence the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### RHEL / CentOS

`yum install gcc` should work. Try `sudo yum install gcc`.

If [`yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-7-redhat-linux-install-gcc-compiler-development-tools/) does not work, add `sudo` in front of it as well.

Check your [repositories](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/265523): `yum repolist all`

Comment: i ran the command and got the error as :    Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
@MC10 please help

Comment: Check your [repositories](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/265523). Are you [subscribed to a specific channel](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25567/124882)?

Comment: @user3407271 What do you see if you run `yum repolist all`? Are your repositories enabled?

Comment: the repositories status is showing disabled.so maybe i won't be able to download gcc i guess.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it isn't finding a package named solely *gcc*. That is too broad. Do a `yum search gcc` to see all of the gcc packages, and the full package name. Then you'll be able to install the correct one. It'll probably be something like `yum install gcc 4.x` And as others said, don't forget to be in `root` or do `sudo. I've had this same thing happen to me a few times.